# Как запустить сайт на OpenServer?

Tags: php, openserver

Есть папка в директории domains, пусть будет some_domain. В ней есть папка public, в которой находится index.php. Вот что нужно сделать, чтобы при подключению к корню домена отображалось все правильно?

**UPD:** или маршруты нужно в htaccess прописывать? Или в Nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно запустить open Server (не забыть запустить его в трее, у часов) и перейти в браузере по адресу http://some_domain/ . Public указывать нет необходимости - эта директория входит в список директория для автоопределения 9public_html www\htdocs www http htdocs web httpdocs public html site)

Answer (score -1):

в браузере набрать `some_domain/public/`

и сайт отобразиться

Comment: нет так не работает...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?